# Xamarin NavigationPage PushAsync Crashes

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

#### Description

Xamarin application crashes upon awaiting NavigationPage.Pushaync().
NavigationPage.Asyncpush() is called within a ButtonClicked Method.

```
private async void OnAboutUsClicked()
{
    var modifiedContactPage = new ModifiedContact() { BackgroundColor = ResourceColourModel.BackgroundColor };
    await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(modifiedContactPage);
}
```

#### Reproduce steps

Page.Xaml with a button that has binding property 
PageViewModel which contains declaration of binding property
and buttonClick event Handler

#### Expected behavior

To navigate to new page

#### Actual behavior:

Crashes with Samsung Galaxy S21 upon clicking button that contains 
NavigationPage.PushAsync()

#### Basic Information:

Android Build:
-minimum level 21 
-Target level 30
Device: 
-Samsung Galaxy S21

Comment: Which exception causes the crash?  If the debugger isn't showing you the details, use try/catch around the suspect code to capture it.  This is basic level debugging you should be able to do before asking for help.

Comment: I never added an exception to this question because the app is being tested as an internal test on google play. The app does not crash when testing on an emulator device or other android devices. Luckily, I know the user that tested the app. So I will come back after having done a test with the user's device.

Comment: You can try to integrate [App Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/xamarin) To analyze the exception in release mode .

Comment: Did you happen to utilize Xamarin.Forms ListView from modifiedContactPage.xaml ??

Answer (score 0):

Post your exception. But probably you need to write this in your
`App.xaml.cs` constructor code:

```
public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        }
```