# Xamarin App opens different Page from Navigation.PushAsync() Page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

#### Description

Xamarin application opens different Page upon  NavigationPage.Pushaync().
NavigationPage.Asyncpush() is called within a ButtonClicked Method.
That different page used to be the one being pushed but it no longer is.

ViewModel.cs

```
private async void OnAboutUsClicked()
{
    var modifiedContactUs = new ModifiedContactUs() { BackgroundColor = ResourceColourModel.BackgroundColor };
    await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(modifiedContactUs);
}
```

ModifiedContactUs.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Project.Views.Pages.ModifiedContact"
             xmlns:mapObject="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Grid BackgroundColor="white">
                <mapObject:Map x:Name="mapId" HasZoomEnabled="True" MapType="Street">

                </mapObject:Map>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

ModifiedContactUs.xaml.cs

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Project.Views.Pages
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ModifiedContactUs : ContentPage
    {
        public ModifiedContactUs()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

ContactUs.xaml(The different Page)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<customControl:CustomContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:map ="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
    xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms"
    xmlns:customControl="clr-namespace:Project.CustomControls.Renderers"
    xmlns:templates_navbar="clr-namespace:Project.Views.Templates.Menus"
    xmlns:fontAwesome="clr-namespace:Project._Utilities"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="Project.Views.Pages.ContactUs"
    >

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent" Spacing="0">
            
            <templates_navbar:NavBar DotMenu_IsVisible="False" BackButton_IsVisible="True"/>

            <Grid BackgroundColor="white">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height=".33*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height=".07*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height=".6*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width=".3*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Padding="10">
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label 
                                Text="Company Name" 
                                FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                FontSize="Medium"
                                FontFamily="Lato-Bold"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                                />
                            <Label
                                Text="{Binding Address}" 
                                FontFamily="Lato-Bold"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                />
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label 
                                Text="Opening Times"
                                FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                FontSize="Medium" 
                                FontFamily="Lato-Bold"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                                />
                            <Label
                                x:Name="weekdays_lbl"
                                Text="{Binding Weekday}"
                                FontFamily="Lato-Bold"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                                />
                            <Label 
                                x:Name="weekend_lbl" 
                                Text="{Binding Weekend}" 
                                FontFamily="Lato-Bold"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                                />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="1">
                        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

                            <Button 
                                x:Name="CallUsBtn" 
                                Text="Call Us"
                                TextColor="White"
                                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColour}"
                                FontFamily="Lato-Bold" 
                                FontSize="12"
                                BorderWidth="2" 
                                BorderColor="White" 
                                Margin="1" 
                                CornerRadius="22" 
                                Command="{Binding PhoneCommand}"
                                />

                            <Button 
                                x:Name="MessageUsBtn" 
                                Text="Message" 
                                TextColor="White"
                                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColour}"
                                FontFamily="Lato-Bold" 
                                FontSize="12" 
                                BorderWidth="2" 
                                BorderColor="White" 
                                Margin="1" 
                                CornerRadius="22" 
                                Command="{Binding EmailCommand}"
                                />

                            <Button 
                                x:Name="RequestCallBack" 
                                Text="Request CallBack"
                                TextColor="White"
                                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AccentColour}"
                                FontFamily="Lato-Bold" 
                                FontSize="11" 
                                BorderWidth="2" 
                                BorderColor="White" 
                                Margin="1" 
                                CornerRadius="22"
                                Command="{Binding CallbackCommand}"
                                />

                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>

                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="1" Padding="5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width=".25*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width=".25*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width=".25*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width=".25*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="0">
                        <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <Image
                                Source="{FontImage FontFamily={StaticResource MaterialFontFamily},
                                Glyph={x:Static fontAwesome:IconFonts.Facebook}, Color=#1877F2,Size=60}"
                                HeightRequest="80"
                                />
                            <Button Clicked="SocialMediaBtnHandler" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Margin="5, 0" CommandParameter="facebook"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="1">
                        <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <Image 
                                Source="{FontImage FontFamily={StaticResource MaterialFontFamily},
                                Glyph={x:Static fontAwesome:IconFonts.Twitter}, Color=#00ACED, Size=60}"/>
                            <Button Clicked="SocialMediaBtnHandler" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Margin="5, 0" CommandParameter="twitter"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="2">
                        <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <Image
                                Source="{FontImage FontFamily={StaticResource MaterialFontFamily},
                                Glyph={x:Static fontAwesome:IconFonts.Linkedin}, Color=#0E76A8, Size=60}"/>
                            <Button Clicked="SocialMediaBtnHandler" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Margin="5, 0" CommandParameter="linkedIn"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="3">
                        <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="2">
                            <ffimageloading:SvgCachedImage
                                Source="social_logo_instagram.png"
                                HeightRequest="40"/>
                            <Button Clicked="SocialMediaBtnHandler" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Margin="5, 0" CommandParameter="instagram"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>

                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                    <Grid>
                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Padding="5">
                            <map:Map x:Name="mapObject" HasZoomEnabled="True" MapType="Street">
                                <map:Map.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <map:Pin
                                            Position="{Binding Position}"
                                            Address="{Binding Address}"
                                            Label="{Binding PlaceName}"
                                            />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </map:Map.ItemTemplate>
                            </map:Map>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>


            </Grid>

            <AbsoluteLayout  BackgroundColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="SizeProportional">


            </AbsoluteLayout>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</customControl:CustomContentPage>
```

ContactUs.xaml.cs (The different page)

```
using Project._SharedData;
using Project.CustomControls.Renderers;
using Project.Models;
using Project.ViewModels;
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services;
using System;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Project.Views.Pages
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class ContactUsPage : CustomContentPage
    {
        ContactUsVM _ContactUsVM;
        public ContactUsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = _ContactUsVM = new ContactUsVM();
            initMap();

            configureDisplay();

            setFontOpeningTime();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            _ContactUsVM.OnAppearing();
            configureDisplay();
        }

        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
            _ContactUsVM.OnDisappearing();

            try
            {
                if (PopupNavigation.Instance != null)
                    PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync(true);
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }

        private void setFontOpeningTime()
        {
            DayOfWeek day = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;

            // Set the font based on whether current day is weekday or weekend
            if ((day == DayOfWeek.Saturday) || (day == DayOfWeek.Sunday))
            {
                weekend_lbl.FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold;
            }
            else
            {
                weekdays_lbl.FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold;
            }
        }

        private void configureDisplay()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SharedPrefs.UserSessionEmail))
            {
                RequestCallBack.IsVisible = true;
                MessageUsBtn.Text = "Email";
            }
            else
            {
                RequestCallBack.IsVisible = false;
                MessageUsBtn.Text = "Message";
            }
        }

        private async void SocialMediaBtnHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string socialMediaName = (sender as Button).CommandParameter.ToString().ToLower();
            await Launcher.OpenAsync(SocialMediaModel.WebLink(socialMediaName));
        }



        private void initMap()
        {
            try
            {
                double latitude = Convert.ToDouble(SharedData.CompanyDetailsList[0].Latitude);
                double longitude = Convert.ToDouble(SharedData.CompanyDetailsList[0].Longitude);

                mapObject.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(latitude, longitude), Distance.FromMeters(100)));

                mapObject.ItemsSource = SharedData.CompanyDetailsList;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Expected behavior

To navigate to a new Page named ModifiedContactUs

#### Actual behavior:

Navigates to page called named ContactUs

#### Basic Information:

Android Build:
-minimum level 21 
-Target level 30
Devices: 
-Huawei Y6 2019 
-API level 29


-Pixel 5 
-API level 30

#### Notes

This question is different to from the [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71529505/xamarin-navigationpage-pushasync-crashes)  I asked recently (Where the device crashes). This is behavior happens on all devices I test on except the one from that [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71529505/xamarin-navigationpage-pushasync-crashes)

Comment: does this behavior happen while you're debugging on the device?

Answer (score 0):

> Expected behavior
> To navigate to a new Page named ModifiedContactPage

> Actual behavior:
> Navigates to page called named ContactUsPage

From your code I saw you just push to `ModifiedContactUs` not `ModifiedContactPage` .

```
var modifiedContactUs = new ModifiedContactUs() { BackgroundColor = ResourceColourModel.BackgroundColor };
await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(modifiedContactUs);
```

#### Suggestion

1. Try to add breakpoint to see if it triggers button click event es expected .
2. Delete the old class and try again .
3. Delete the app from the device and try again .

Comment: Sorry, I entered inconsistent class names as I was trying to hide the real names. I adjusted them now in the post. We have: ModifiedContactUs and ContactUs

Comment: Did you try my suggestion ?

Comment: Yeah, I just did but it never hit the breakpoint. I attempted to adjsut the settings  in Debug >Option> Enable Just my code. Made sure application is in debug mode and deploy is ticked and in android options debugegr is set to Xamarin. Restart visual studio.

What worked was to go to repo, download/clone the project as a new one. Then I copied the new files, changes and I could step through with the same settings above and this time go into the ModifiedContactUs instead of ContactUs.

Answer (score 0):

This worked: Clone the repo into a new folder as a new project and copy the files and changes to this new repo.

Attempted configuration solutions that did not work: Restarting visual studio. Untick and Tick Debug Mode. Untick and tick Deploy in Configuration Manager under Build. In Android Properties> android Options making sure debugging is checked and debugger is Xamarin.

Comment: If problem has gone you can mark it as answer .